# How to align a widget to bottom right corner in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

this is the output I want.

but I can't align this using the positioned widget.

[image]

this is my output. and I tried the position, and it's not working, how can I achieve this.
here is my code

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: bgColor,
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 190,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                color: containerColor,
              ),
              child: Row(
                // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 130,
                      width: 140,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: bgColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 30,
                    width: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: themeBlueColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
```

how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 190,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.5),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Row(
                  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 4,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 130,
                        width: 140,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.6), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 6,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "iPhone 12 Pro",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Apple iPhone 12th Gen",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.6), fontSize: 14),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 30.0,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              const Text(
                                r"$999",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: 30,
                                width: 60,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
```

It will look something like this -

[image]